# MySql - Retrieve correct values using COALESCE?

Tags: mysql, select, join, coalesce

I have an sql fiddle here:
http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fbd48/1

The colors should be red for flower and brown for bear, but it shows red for both.

Not sure if COALESCE fits here, but was in the accepted answer for something similar here:
[MySQL - Retrieve row value from different table depending on value of row in a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10353813/mysql-retrieve-row-value-from-different-table-depending-on-value-of-row-in-a-t)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT mem.member_name, g.*
, coalesce(f.flower_color, b.bear_color) as color
from members mem
inner join general g on mem.member_id = g.member_id
left join flowers f on g.gift_item_id = f.flower_id AND g.gift_item = 'flower'
left join bears b on g.gift_item_id = b.bear_id AND g.gift_item = 'bear'
WHERE g.month='june'
```

There was no way to differentiate a flower from a bear, so I added tests to the joins. This is pretty smelly. you might rethink your schema.

Comment: Smelly how? As in heavy on the DB or cluttered query?

Comment: You have the type of the gift encoded in the name of the table AND in the general table. You have a lot of work to do if you ever want to give someone a funny balloon. A single gift table with a gift_type field might be a better approach.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to work if you use unique gift item IDs.

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c02c8/1

Comment: I know:) But IDs can be the same in different tables, so I'm looking for a solutions that will differentiate based on 'flower' or 'bear' instead of running into issues with the IDs